# Meaning of a sentence with "economically"

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a comment in the film called "Plasticized"(http://www.plasticizedthemovie.com/about-the-film/).

> The philosophy that there is an 'away'; that, you know, we say we throw
>   something away. That you can create something to be used for a minute
>   that lasts forever, is evil in my opinion. What I think needs to
>   happen with people who, companies that produce plastic is in the whole
>   scope of the products impact, **they need to calculate for its
>   environmental impact economically.**

What does it mean **they need to calculate for its environmental impact economically**? Does it mean, "plastic producing companies need to consider its environmental impact and ecnomical impact for the environment?

Comment: It's not worded very clearly, but I think it means something like *"they need to take into account the economic cost of its environmental impact"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is improvised speech rather than formally composed speech, so it's not altogether coherent; but what I take that sentence to mean is that the people who use plastic and companies which produce it should include the environmental impact in their calculation of the economic cost. That is, plastic is cheap; but if you consider its environmental impact, too, it is more expensive.